# select row_to_json table, error: must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I get this message `column "mi.*" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` what does that means? and how to solve it?
I tried change `GROUP BY m.id` to `GROUP BY m.id, mi.media_id`  still same error

I test this if I remove `GROUP BY m.id ORDER BY COUNT(mua.id)` it works

data structure

```
[ { id: 54,
    media_information: {
      id: 1,
      media_id: 54
    }
  }, 
]
```

query

```
SELECT
  m.*,
  row_to_json(mi.*) as media_information
  FROM media m 
  LEFT JOIN media_information mi ON mi.media_id = m.id

  LEFT JOIN media_user_action mua ON mua.media_id = m.id

  GROUP BY m.id
  ORDER BY COUNT(mua.id)
  ...
```

table

```
media
id | ...
1

media_information
id | media_id fk media.id | ...
1  |  1

media_user_action
id | media_id fk media.id | user_id
1  | 1                    | 1
2  | 1                    | 3
```

UPDATE  base on below anser

```
Select m2.*
From media m2
LEFT JOIN media_user_action mua ON mua.media_id = m2.id

Where m2.id in (
  SELECT
      m.*,
      row_to_json(mi.*) as media_information
      FROM media m 
      LEFT JOIN media_information mi ON mi.media_id = m.id
)

GROUP BY m2.id
ORDER BY COUNT(mua.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the grouping first and then do a join like

```
SELECT
  m.*,
  row_to_json(mi.*) as media_information
  FROM media m 
  LEFT JOIN media_information mi ON mi.media_id = m.id

  LEFT JOIN (select media_id, COUNT(id) as mua_count
             from media_user_action
             group by media_id) xxx ON xxx.media_id = m.id

  ORDER BY xxx.mua_count;
```

Comment: @karina, your query may return the correct result but it will have performance hit based on the volume of data since you are performing a correlated subquery and so for every row of outer your inner query getting evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

All the non aggregated columns in your select column must be in the group by clause. So since you are doing m.* you would have to put every column in the group by

If you want every column from the table you should turn your current query into a subquery like so:

```
Select m2.*
From media m2
Where m2.id in (subselect)
```

So the reason you have to put every non aggregated column into the group by?  Ambiguity

Consider this. You have a table full of names and birthdays. You want to group by birthday to get a count

```
Select name, birthday, count(birthday)
From thetable
Group by birthday
```

So what should the db return in the name column when multiple people are all born on the same day?

Edit. After actually reading your query this is what I think you are trying to get at

```
Select m.*,  row_to_json(mi.*) as media_information, (select count(*) from media_user_action mua where mua.media_id = m.id ) mua_count
From media m 
LEFT JOIN media_information mi ON mi.media_id = m.id 
ORDER BY mua_count
```

Comment: what do you mean put every column?

Comment: please see my update does that correct? I leave `LEFT JOIN media_user_action mua ON mua.media_id = m2.id` in outside

Comment: @user1575921 can you explain what you are trying to retrieve in plain English?  I.e. all media that has media information and the count of media user action?

Answer (score 1):

Do group by in subselect. I don't have your structure - so perhaps it wouldn't work - so please treat is as a sample:

```
SELECT
 m.*,
 row_to_json(mi.*) as media_information
FROM media m 
 JOIN media_information mi ON mi.media_id = m.id
 JOIN media_user_action mua ON mua.media_id = m.id
 JOIN (
  SELECT
   m.id, count(mua.id) as cnt
  FROM media m 
   JOIN media_information mi ON mi.media_id = m.id
   JOIN media_user_action mua ON mua.media_id = m.id
  GROUP BY m.id) as counts on m.id = counts.id
  ORDER BY counts.cnt
```